# Escaping quotes inside quotes in html

Tags: java, html, jsp

Not sure why this error is happening in Chrome and Edge, but not in IE (yeah business team is still stuck with it)

Seeing "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input"  on this html line

```
<TR onmouseover="rowColor(this, true);" onmouseout="rowColor(this, false);" onclick='workTicket('displayTicket.action?TICKETID=1367698&amp;TTID=14','1367698');'>
```

and the following is the corresponding jsp/struts line

```
<TR onmouseover="rowColor(this, true);" onmouseout="rowColor(this, false);" onclick='workTicket(<c:out value="'displayTicket.action?TICKETID=${dispTO.ticketNbr}&TTID=${dispTO.ticketTypeId}','${dispTO.ticketNbr}'" />);'>
```

I don't see anything wrong in the above line except the onclick attribute starts with single quote. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

You MUST have a complete set of OTHER quotes inside an attribute

```
<TR onmouseover="rowColor(this, true);" 
 onmouseout="rowColor(this, false);" 
  onclick="workTicket('displayTicket.action?TICKETID=1367698&amp;TTID=14','1367698');">
```

There is no problem with the c:out

```
<TR onmouseover="rowColor(this, true);" 
onmouseout="rowColor(this, false);" 
onclick="workTicket(<c:out value="'displayTicket.action?TICKETID=${dispTO.ticketNbr}&TTID=${dispTO.ticketTypeId}','${dispTO.ticketNbr}'" />);">
```

will work

BUT this is in my opinion better

```
data-tickettypeid="<c:out value="${dispTO.ticketTypeId}" />"
data-ticketnbr="<c:out value="${dispTO.ticketNbr}" />"
onclick="workTicket(`displayTicket.action?TICKETID=${this.dataset.tickettypeid}&TTID=${this.dataset.ticketnbr}`,this.dataset.tickettypeid)"
```

and even better:

```
document.getElementById("myTable").addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target.closest("tr");
  if (tgt && tgt.getAttribute("data-tickettypeid")) {
    workTicket(`displayTicket.action?TICKETID=${tgt.dataset.tickettypeid}&TTID=${tgt.dataset.ticketnbr}`,tgt.dataset.tickettypeid)
  }
})
```

then you can use

```
<tr data-tickettypeid="<c:out value="${dispTO.ticketTypeId}" />"
data-ticketnbr="<c:out value="${dispTO.ticketNbr}" />">
```

As for the mouseover and out, use CSS